# CakePHP 3 : Image upload from controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I am trying to uploading image from controller using PHP. Here image upload is working fine but content is not saving in database, only image path saving. If I comment on image upload code then content is add in database fine.

Here is my code that I have tried

```
    <?= $this->Form->create($news,array('type'=>'file')) ?>
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('newsImage',['type'=>'file']);
                    echo $this->Form->input('title',['class'=>'form-control']);
                    echo $this->Form->input('news');
                ?>
            </div>
   <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And in controller I have tried below code for upload image

```
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                $target_dir = "img/news/";
                $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["newsImage"]["name"]);

                $fNAME   = $_FILES["newsImage"]["name"];
                $TMPNAME = $_FILES['newsImage']['tmp_name'];

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["newsImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);


                $this->request->data['News']['newsImage']=$fNAME;

                $news = $this->News->patchEntity($news, $this->request->data);
                if ($this->News->save($news)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The news has been saved.'));
                    //return $this->redirect($this->referer()); 
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The news could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
}
```

Here only image directory saving in database, title and news not saving.

Comment: I don't think you want that `['News']` level in the data. Take a look at the contents of `$this->request->data` and match fields that you create to that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $this->request->data['newsImage']=$fNAME;
>
> After this add this line
>
> $news=$this->News->newEntity();

After add this code ur controller looks like:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $target_dir = "img/news/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["newsImage"]["name"]);

   $fNAME   = $_FILES["newsImage"]["name"];
   $TMPNAME = $_FILES['newsImage']['tmp_name'];

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["newsImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);


   $this->request->data['newsImage']=$fNAME;

   $news=$this->News->newEntity();
   $news = $this->News->patchEntity($news, $this->request->data);
   if ($this->News->save($news)) {
       $this->Flash->success(__('The news has been saved.'));
       //return $this->redirect($this->referer()); 
       return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
   } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The news could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There has only one problem,

```
$this->request->data['News']['newsImage']=$fNAME;
```

To

```
$this->request->data['newsImage']=$fNAME;
```

In cakephp 3 you don't need define model name. You can use browser inspector element to see field name, then match between cakephp-2 and cakephp 3 form then you can see the changed.